# Show $2m(R\textbf{x})\cdot \textbf{a} +m\|R\textbf{a}\|^2=m\|R\textbf{x}\|^2+m\|R(\textbf{a}-\textbf{x}) \|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I need to show that
$$2m(R\textbf{x})\cdot \textbf{a} +m\|R\textbf{a}\|^2=m\|R\textbf{x}\|^2+m\|R(\textbf{a}-\textbf{x})
\|^2$$
Here $R=I-P$ where $P=UU^T$, and $\textbf{a},\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $ \|*\|$ is the $L_2$ norm.
I can expand this to $$2m(R\textbf{x})\cdot \textbf{a}+m(\textbf{a}^TR^TR\textbf{a}) = 2m(R^TR\textbf{x})\cdot \textbf{a}+m(\textbf{a}^TR^TR\textbf{a})$$
But I'm not sure where to go from here. Do I need to multply by $\textbf{x}^T $ some where?

This comes from this [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKvnm.png)

Comment: Some typo in your equation: Try putting $x=0$, you will get $||Ra||^2 = m ||Ra||^2$. This is assuming $m$ is a constant. what is $m$ by the way ?

Comment: m is length of the vectors

Comment: Is it $(Rx).Ra$  or just $(Rx).a$?

Comment: its just $(Rx)\cdot a$ I added a priture where it comes from

Answer (score 0):

Just expand: $$(a-x)^TR^TR(a-x) = a^T R^T R a + x^T R^T R x + a^T R^T R x + x^T R^T R a$$

Assuming $U$ has orthogonal columns:
$$R^TR = (I-UU^T)(I-UU^T) = I-UU^T = R$$

Substituting above:
$$(a-x)^TR^TR(a-x) = a^T R^T R a + x^T R^T R x + a^T R x + x^T R^T a$$
$$(a-x)^TR^TR(a-x) = a^T R^T R a + x^T R^T R x + 2 Rx.a$$
$$||R(a-x)||^2 = ||R a||^2 + ||R x||^2 + 2 Rx.a$$

The above is the equation used in the picture you mentioned in the question. Hope above helps. But in the equation you mentioned in the question there is a sign flip. Let me know exactly what is the equation.

Comment: The problem I'm working on is $E_w(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}w_i\text{dist}(x_i,A)^2.$ So i was just wondering how the book got there.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided $m$ is a constant (the number of terms) and the equality you need to show is $$-2(R\bar{x})\cdot a+\|Ra\|^2\\ =-\|R\bar{x}\|^2+\|R(\bar{x}-a)\|^2$$ where $\bar{x}=\sum_{i=1}^mx_i.$ The equality is obvious due to the property of the inner product
$$\|u-v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2-2u\cdot v$$ where $u=R\bar{x}$ and $v=Ra.$ The form of $R$ is irrelevant. The linearity of $R$ is sufficient.